# How to get the list of tables and their columns in a database which are having a specific keyword in their name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have to make a list of tables and their columns that are having keyword 'EMP' in their column name. The database is having around 160 tables. Is there any way of finding this quick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a go

```
SELECT  TABLE_NAME, 
        COLUMN_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME LIKE '%YoutValue%'
ORDER BY    TABLE_NAME, 
            ORDINAL_POSITION
```

**EDIT**

You could use

```
    SELECT  TABLE_NAME, 
            COLUMN_NAME
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_NAME LIKE '%YoutValue%'
    OR    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%YoutValue%'
    ORDER BY    TABLE_NAME, 
                ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: Yes its working thanks ! Further if i have to search column name i would just use in where clause COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%YoutValue%'